# iterate through ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a ajax call that gets me a json containing holiday dates.
Now i want to convert the dates to moments and store them in an array. 
But my code doesn't seem to work properly. I just get empty arrays.

```
var holidays=[]
$.ajax({
    url: 'holiday.html',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        type: 'getHolidays',
        start: intervalStart,
        end: intervalEnd,
    },
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data,function(index,holiday){
            holidays.push(moment.unix(holiday["date"]));
        });
    },
});
```

The Json looks like this

```
[
    {
        "date":"1545696000",
        "title":"Christmas Day1"
    },
    {
        "date":"1545782400",
        "title":"Christmas Day2"
    }
]
```

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: have you tried parsing resulting JSON?

Comment: Where are you actually using `holidays`? How are you determining that it's empty? This seems most likely to be a problem with how you've structured your logic - ie. you're not using the async pattern properly.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan 1. I am using holidays in a fullcalendar while the view is rendered, to add the holiday class to the day, but i didnt inculde it, since there is no problem.
2. I checked it with a console.log(holidays);

Comment: Right, but *where* have you put those lines of code? If they aren't in the `success` handler function where you're building the array, or in a block which is called from it, then this isn't going to work.

Comment: I think you dismiss that ajax is working async. So you try to put async: false in ajax  settings, or you can write the related code in success event.

Comment: @VecihiBaltacı never use `async: false`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, sometimes we have to use it. It Depends on case.

Comment: There's only one case when you can validly use it; `onbeforeunload`. In *every* other case you should be using promises and/or callbacks. This is why the browser shows warnings in the console when it detects a sync XMLHttpRequest being sent.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is completely fine you just need to handle async behaviour of javascript. Like you have to use holidays array after sucsess

```
var holidays=[]
$.ajax({
    url: 'holiday.html',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        type: 'getHolidays',
        start: intervalStart,
        end: intervalEnd,
    },
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data,function(index,holiday){
            holidays.push(moment.unix(holiday["date"]));
            call_your_remaining_code_here();
        });
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your ajax call;

**async : false**